# Node Js delivering files to Client

Tags: javascript, node.js

When you send an `HTML` file to the client, it gets parsed and makes `GET` calls for anything else like `<SCRIPT>` or `<LINK>` (is `<IMG>` included in that? I think it is).

It is very expensive to do this process:

- Ask for file - CLIENT
- Read file from disk - NODE
- Publish contents to Response Stream - NODE
- Read response stream - CLIENT

Is there anyway to cache the file contents in Node when the server starts up in order to simply do

- Ask for file - CLIENT
- Publish contents to Response Stream - NODE
- Read Response Stream - CLIENT

I've got this function to go through all the scripts in the `Scripts/` folder and read the files:

```
var gatherFiles = function () {
    fs.readdir('/Scripts', function (err, files) {
        files.filter(function (file) {
            return path.extname(file) == '.js';
        }).forEach(function (file) {
            // read files here
        });
    });
};
```

Bare in mind these points

- Its on a Raspberry Pi, it DOESN'T need to be scalable
- I don't mind if it is expensive at the start

I assume, that because the server should only be started once, that if all the files were cached in node at the beginning, then if they were ever needed then they can be served up from memory. The files are script files so they aren't massive, `100Kb` max really (after minified probably much less).

I ask this, because when I've done the `Chrome` and `Firefox` network monitor to see how long it takes to serve out the files, and it takes a very long time, over `100ms`....

I'm guessing there is latency across many parts of the server: ethernet, SD card, code.

So I think the way I want to do it with pre caching, it should minimise that `100ms` lag.

*** My Solution ***

```
var fs = require ("fs"),
    path = require("path"),
    async = require("async"),
    scriptFiles = {};

function gatherFiles(callback, folder) {
    fs.readdir(folder, function (err, files) {
        var filteredFiles = files.filter(function (file) {
            var ext = path.extname(file);
            return ext == '.js' || ext == '.html';
        });
        aync.each(filteredFiles, function (file, asynCallback) {
            if (!scriptFiles[file])
                fs.readFile(folder + '/' + file, function (err, data) {
                    scriptFiles[file] = data;
                    asyncCallback();
                });
        }, function (err) {
            callback(scriptFiles);
        });
    });
};

exports.gatherFiles = gatherFiles;
```

The key points to note are:

- Async each requires you to have a callback fired to let it know that a function has completed, when it has detected all callbacks have been fired then it will call the final callback, also this allows for errors to permiate through.
- In the final callback it calls the main function callback and passes through the file dictionary with data, the anonymous function should then start the http server

usage:

```
var cacher = require("./cacher");
cacher.gatherFiles(function (fileDictionary) {
    http.createServer(onRequest, 8888);
}, './Scripts');
```

Comment: Just make sure you've added the proper headers, and the static files will be cached by the browser.

Comment: @adeneo I think No1_Melman wants to cache the files on the server side (not by the browser) to avoid multiple file reads.

Comment: @san.chez - I got that, I just don't see why

Comment: @adeneo it's because it's expensive everytime they're called from the server

Comment: It's really not, Node can handle millions of requests for static resources without issues, and considering the static resources are only requested by the browser the first time, as they should be cached the next time, it's one of the least expensive things you've got. Also, compare the disk read speed, the memory speed and the network speed of most users, and think about what takes the longest.

Comment: all i'm trading off in my question is memory speed and disk speed of the raspberry pi. @adeneo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this would meet what you're looking for, which is trying to eliminate the disk read.

```
function Files = function () {
    var files = {};

    return function (filepath, callback) {
        // If cache is available, return that
        if (files[filepath]) return callback(null, files[filepath]);
        // Otherwise, get it, then store it
        fs.readFile(filepath, function (err, data) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            files[filepath] = data;
            callback(null, data);
        });
    }
}();
```

Then call it as such

```
Files('/scripts/whatever.js', function (err, data) {
   // Do something
});
```

If you want to, you can add in other functions such as file watching or cache expiration you can.

If you want to cache it all in the beginning, you can just iterate through whatever directory and do nothing with the callback.

For that I'd modify it as such:

```
//...
if (files[filepath]) return callback && callback(null, files[filepath]); 
//...
callback && callback(null, data);
//...
```

The `callback && callback(...)` will be treated the same as `if (false && alert("Nothing"))` in that the alert will never be reached, because the falsy condition prevents further execution. As such, if you don't pass a callback, it will never try to execute the callback. Sort of a fail safe.

Comment: that, my friend, is an excellent answer, much appreciate for the time and effort :)

Comment: @No1_Melman Please let us know the result. How much did it minimise the 100ms lag?

Comment: @san.chez , I'm implementing now, will post back the results in a bit

Comment: Current Stats are (old implementation) it takes less then `40ms` to send and receive a file, however, it takes `103ms` to actually call for the script files.

Comment: @san.chez there is a `200ms` saving when pre caching the files, i'll post an edit to my answer with how I did it

Comment: @san.chez sorry, the current stats are on one file, there are 2 being uploaded. overall the no caching way takes about 500ms, the pre cache takes less than 300ms. Try it yourself, i can supply you my files, load up a vm with node on it.

Comment: @san.chez i did a test inside firefox on the vm, and there is about a 100ms saving by precaching!